Where can the Pauli Exclusion Principle be found in DFT?
DFT involves many important approximations that make the calculation of electron behavior in matter possible.
Electrons have spins, and we can expect same-spin pairs to be further apart on average than opposite-spin pairs. (cf. Pauli Exclusion Principe)
One way to take that into account might be to include an effective potential to approximate the effect.
Is that what happens in DFT? If so, where exactly (in what part of the calculation) and how?

I've just started to look at Diola Bagayoko (2014) Understanding density functional theory (DFT) and completing it in practice and while I don't see "Pauli" or "exclusion" I do see the term "exchange potential", which makes me wonder if it lies in there somewhere.

To answer the question in the title:
It depends on what you mean exactly. For example, in principle DFT (Hohenberg-Kohn, Kohn-Sham) works completely analogous as well for (indistinguishable) bosons. Hence, the overall answer must be: Nowhere, a priori.
If, however, you consider (indistinguishable) fermions, then the "Pauli principle", or, let's better say the anti-symmetrization postulate, is indeed at work. For example, it appears in the definition of the sets of $N$- and $v$-representable densities. As such, it is important for various minimization principles.
Another example in the case of indistinguishable fermions is Levy's functional for $N$-representable densities $n$, which reads
$$F[n]:=\min\limits_{\psi \in \wedge^N H\\\psi\mapsto n} \langle \psi, T+W\psi\rangle\quad ,$$
and where the minimization takes place on (a subset of) the anti-symmetrized subspace of the $N$-particle Hilbert space, reflecting the Pauli principle.

Regarding my second paragraph: What anyway is (trivially) true is that the Pauli Principle appears in the definitions of these sets. But one might ask what this implies for these sets, as compared to e.g. the bosonic. For 1-RDMs, there is a (huge) difference; for densities I don't know. For example, the set of $N$-representable admissible densities (in the Lieb sense) coincide for bosons and fermions (Lieb's famous 1983 paper). Perhaps there is some literature or a nice example, but I couldn't find something. All of this of course also depends on the exact setting one considers.

For example, consider the spinless (Bose-)Hubbard model with $2<N<L$. For bosons, there are $N$-representable densities such that $n(i)>1$ (which could also be $v$-representable, e.g. if one allows to set $t=0$). But no fermionic $N$ particle state can produce these densities due to the Pauli principle/anti-symmetry. For this setting the sets thus differ.

You are vastly mistaken (as younger I, too, was).
The difference between the exact experimental results and the Hartree-Fock approximation result, is defined to be the correlation.
It is known that correlation tends to undo exchange interaction term. We even know from theoretical analysis of the problem, i.e. without taking the Slater determinant approximation and instead using proper group theory methods to extract as much of the exact solution as we can, that this is true with great generality.
It certainly also does not help that the Slater determinant step is very computationally intensive.
All these together, makes it such that it is sensible to try to get rid of the Slater determinant entirely. Simply don't do the Slater determinant, i.e. completely ignore Pauli's Exclusion Principle, and instead approximate both the exchange and correlation with functionals. That's the origin of the name. That's what they do.

The question about the Pauli exclusion principle in DFT is quite interesting.
The Pauli exclusion principle has two aspects:
one is whether a single state can only be occupied by one electron,
and the other is that it seems to generate additional interaction forces.
I will explain these two points below.
DFT incorporates the Pauli exclusion principle in a minimal sense.
When deriving the DFT and Kohn-Sham equations,
we define the electron charge density (per unit cell) as:
$$
n =
\sum_{\varepsilon_i \le E_\mathrm{F}}{\sum_{i}{\psi_i^* \psi_i}}
$$
Here, $\varepsilon_i$ ($\psi_i$) represents the energy (wave function)
of each state, and i is the index of the state. Alternatively,
$$
n =
\sum_{i}{\lambda_i \psi_i^* \psi_i}
$$
Here, $0 \le \lambda_i \le 1$ indicates the occupation of the state.
Thus, the Pauli exclusion principle is inherently embedded in DFT through
the definition of charge density.
In practical DFT simulations, we calculate the
$$
\mathrm{DOS}(E) = \sum_{i}{\psi_i^*(\varepsilon_i=E) \psi_i(\varepsilon_i)}
$$
and determine a suitable $E_\mathrm{F}$ such that
$$
n = \sum_{E \le E_\mathrm{F}}{\mathrm{DOS}(E)}
$$
On the other hand, in the derivation of the Kohn-Sham equation,
an extra exchange-correlation term is introduced.
This term actually incorporates many spin-related interactions and,
to some extent, substitutes the effects of the Pauli exclusion principle.
You may notice that I referred to it as "minimal Pauli exclusion principle." (My personal naming)
This is because the many-particle effects are eliminated in DFT,
resulting in what we call the "single-particle picture."
(The results in most solid-state physics textbooks are derived based on the single-particle picture,
which is sufficient for systems like metals and semiconductors.)
Therefore, although the Pauli exclusion principle reflects the differences between bosons and fermions,
fermionic properties do not fully manifest in DFT.
(For instance, the wave function's sign change after exchanging two particles.)

Welcome to Stack Exchange! It's great when a new user drops in and posts an enlightening answer right away.
